# Jade lang - how to add a new line manually?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, template-engine

I have a code like this

```
ul.nav
    li.item
        a(href='#')
        ul
            li
                a(href='#')
```

It converts to

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="item"><a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Expected result:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="item">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get a right indentation?

I have tried `Whitespace Removal: > and <` rules from http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade-syntax.html, but they don't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is this regarding `node.js`/`javascript` (tags) or `scalate`/`scala` (documentation link)? If the tags are right, the documentation is at https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme.

Comment: there is no info in documention for this question

Comment: The output you're expecting isn't currently supported. [`jade`](http://jade-lang.com/) prefers to remove as much whitespace as it can, and it [extends this preference](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/0.28.0/lib/compiler.js#L370-L371) to ["inline" elements](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/0.28.0/lib/inline-tags.js) even with [`pretty` printing](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#options) enabled. Might be worthy of a [feature request](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues), if it hasn't been asked for before.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'm searching for some workaround of this.

Answer (score 2):

Manually new lines between  can be added with such command

```
= "\n"
```

so when your code looks like this:

```
ul.nav
li.item
    a(href='#')
    ul
        li
            = "\n"
            a(href='#')
```

following output is produced:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="item"><a href="#"></a>
    <ul>
      <li>
<a href="#"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the only problem is that this command breaks tabulation indents.

Found on project issues [page](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/921)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [html](https://github.com/maxogden/commonjs-html-prettyprinter) module to even more beautify your html. Add the following to your code:

```
var html = require('html');
var fn = jade.compile('string of jade', options);  // standard jade example

console.log(html.prettyPrint(fn()))
```

Your output will be

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="item">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Make sure you are using the latest [beautify-html.js](https://raw.github.com/einars/js-beautify/master/beautify-html.js).

Comment: I'm a bit newbie in node.js. I should install common.js first? Please give a step by step install information.

Comment: well, I installed this package. It gives a messy code and doesn't help as a result.